# get_post_meta not working inside loop

Tags: custom-field, genesis-theme-framework

I was hoping for some assistance with a custom meta box that I added to my genesis child theme.

The data is being saved properly, and stored properly, but when I try to echo it out using get_post_meta, nothing shows up.  But a custom function someone showed me does echo it out.  Can someone figure out what it isn't working?

This should work but doesn't.

```
add_action ('genesis_before_post_content', 'gteh_tagline');
function gteh_tagline() {
    $meta = get_post_meta($post->ID, $field['dbt_text'], true);
    echo $meta;
    }
```

This works but I don't want to use this, would rather use the proper code

```
add_action ('genesis_before_post_content', 'gteh_tagline');
function gteh_tagline() {
    echo "<pre>";
    $customs = get_post_custom(get_the_ID());
    $text = (isset($customs['dbt_text'][0]))?$customs['dbt_text'][0]:"";
    var_dump($customs);
    echo "<br/>text=".$text;
    echo "</pre>";
}
```

It dumps this and echoes it out when asked.

```
["dbt_text"]=>
array(1) {
[0]=>
string(89) "At vero eos et accusamus et iusto odio dignityr simos ducimus qui blanditiis praesentium "
}
```

Here is dbt_text

```
$prefix = 'dbt_';
$meta_box = array(
'id' => 'my-meta-box',
'title' => 'Post Tagline',
'page' => 'post',
'context' => 'normal',
'priority' => 'high',
'fields' => array(
    array(
        'name' => 'Post Tagline',
        'desc' => 'Displayed below the post title',
        'id' => $prefix . 'text',
        'type' => 'text',
        'std' => ''
    )
)
```

);

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing 'improper' about the second block of code. Its just written for debugging purposes. The key difference is that that second block used `get_the_ID()`. Try that.

```
add_action ('genesis_before_post_content', 'gteh_tagline');
function gteh_tagline() {
    $meta = get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), $field['dbt_text'], true);
    echo $meta;
}
```

Or try to pull in `$post` with `global`.

```
add_action ('genesis_before_post_content', 'gteh_tagline');
function gteh_tagline() {
    global $post;
    $meta = get_post_meta($post->ID, $field['dbt_text'], true);
    echo $meta;
}
```

Or, depending on how that action is written, this ***might*** work.

```
add_action ('genesis_before_post_content', 'gteh_tagline');
function gteh_tagline($post) {
    $meta = get_post_meta($post->ID, $field['dbt_text'], true);
    echo $meta;
}
```

Comment: aah, didn't see your answer before i added one..

Comment: :) @PontusAbrahamsson  No worries. I've done that a dozen times.

Comment: Odd.  I tried using get_the_ID() before posting this.  It didn't work.  I tried adding global $post;  gteh_tagline($post) also does nothing.  I am stumped.  THe data is obviously being stored.

Comment: Does `var_dump($post);` or `var_dump(get_the_ID());` give you anything with any of those combinations?

Answer (score 1):

You need to set `$post` to global within a function:

```
function wpse_16722_tagline() {
    global $post;

    $meta = get_post_meta( $post->ID, $field['dbt_text'], true );
        echo $meta;
    }
add_action ('genesis_before_post_content', 'wpse_16722_tagline');
```

Comment: Thanks I tried adding global $post; but it didn't make a difference.  plus the function is being called from inside the loop.

Comment: This function is hooked, not called within a loop, though that may be where the hook executes. I am not trying to be nit-picky. Just suggesting that you have scope issues you are not thinking about.

Answer (score 1):

Two problems with the first function:

1. Use get_the_ID() or global the $post before using $post->ID.
2. $field['dbt_text'] isn't defined in the function anywhere. Is this supposed to be coming from a global as well?

Edit: After reading your comments and replies to the other answers, I think you don't understand how PHP's variable scoping works. You may want to read up on this in order to understand how variables work inside functions:

http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php

Comment: $field['dbt_text'] is defined elsewhere in functions.php for meta box.  I'll add it to the top.  I've tried get_the_ID() and global $post and neither work.

Comment: Anything "defined elsewhere" is not defined when you're inside a function. Functions have their own variable scope in PHP. You need to get this value from wherever you're getting it from inside every function, or you need to put it into a global variable and then declare that you want to bring that global variable into the function scope inside the function.

Comment: BTW, get_the_ID() and/or using the global $post *do* work, but you're not getting the results you want because $field is not defined inside that function. You need to correct both problems at the same time to get the function to work.